Generate Instagram token issue
i have created an app from Facebook developer - Instagram basic display - Add Tester - Approve Tester from instagram account .. but when i generate token it give me this error
OAuthException: Your account's future activity history off Meta technologies is currently turned off. Please visit account center to change it.
anybody help please
i have created an app from Facebook developer - Instagram basic display - Add Tester - Approve Tester from instagram account .. but when i generate token it give me this error
OAuthException: Your account's future activity history off Meta technologies is currently turned off. Please visit account center to change it.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
